# Getting 'null' while trying to retrieve multiple rows from a table created on IBM Blockchain network

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I've created a Blockchain network on IBM Blockchain (Bluemix, built on Hyperledger). I've added a table using `deploy` function from my chaincode. And then added a couple of rows using the `invoke` function.

The problem is, while I'm **able to** retrieve a **single row** with a key, using `GetRow` function, I'm **not able to** retrieve **multiple rows** using `GetRows` function. The JSON response I get is **null**.

The code I've used is from the following link: [Hyperledger-Fabric-Table](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/bddtests/chaincode/go/table/table.go).

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The chaincode APIs have been updated in Fabric v1.0 and table APIs removed in favor of more intuitive APIs.  See the Fabric marbles02 example for suggested data patterns including various ways to query for multiple records:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/go/marbles02